# Find XML attributes at random

Tags: xml, powershell, xpathnavigator, select-xml

How can I find the 2 attributes `$_.CompleteName` and `$_.Channel` at random?

```
+ $channel | ? {$liste} | get-random <<<<  -min 0 -max $liste.list.groupe.count
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (position:PSObject) [Get-Random 
   ], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Command 
   s.GetRandomCommand
```

**Sample Data**

```
$Xliste = [xml]@"
<list>
   <groupe>
        <position type="General">
            <CompleteName>folder-1</CompleteName>
            <dateYY>2014</dateYY>
            <dateMM>jaenner</dateMM>
            <dateDD>mittwoch</dateDD>
            <Overall_mode>cbr</Overall_mode>
            <Duration>00:1:27</Duration>
            <Overall_rate>96.0Kbps</Overall_rate>
        </position>
        <position type="Version">
            <Channel>channel2</Channel>
            <CodecID>55</CodecID>
            <Duration>00:1:27</Duration>
            <Compression>Lossy</Compression>
            <StreamSize>96.0Kbps</StreamSize>
        </position>
    </groupe>
    <groupe>
        <position type="General">
            <CompleteName>folder-2</CompleteName>
            <dateYY>2013</dateYY>
            <dateMM>maerz</dateMM>
            <dateDD>montag</dateDD>
            <Overall_mode>cbr</Overall_mode>
            <Duration>00:8:12</Duration>
            <Overall_rate>96.0Kbps</Overall_rate>
        </position>
        <position type="Version">
            <Channel>channel1</Channel>
            <CodecID>49</CodecID>
            <Duration>00:8:12</Duration>
            <Compression>Lossy</Compression>
            <StreamSize>96.0Kbps</StreamSize>
        </position>
    </groupe>
</list>
"@
```

**Code**

```
$channel_and_CompleteName = Select-Xml $liste -xpath "*/*/*" | Select-Object -Expand node | ? {$_ -ne ($_.CompleteName)+" "+($_.Channel)}
$channel_and_CompleteName | ? {$liste} | get-random -min 0 -max $liste.list.groupe.count
```

Comment: When you say at random do you mean choose one of the `Channel` and `CompleteName` at random? A random one from each of those two sets? I'm not completely sure what output you are hoping for

Comment: Both your `Where-Object` clauses don't make much sense. Your first major issue is that you need to be using `$Xliste` in your code and not `$liste`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not clear what you are looking for but this will take that XML and select, at random, one of the `Channel` and `CompleteName` pairings as a custom object

```powershell
$Xliste.List.groupe | ForEach-Object{
    $props = @{}
    $_.Position | ForEach-Object{    
        If($_.Type -eq "General"){
            $props.CompleteName =  $_.CompleteName
        } ElseIf($_.Type -eq "Version"){
            $props.Channel =  $_.Channel
        }
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props 
} | Get-Random
```

**Sample Output**

```powershell
CompleteName Channel 
------------ ------- 
folder-1     channel2
```

**Pure String based output**

```powershell
$Xliste.List.groupe | ForEach-Object{
    $string = @()
    $_.Position | ForEach-Object{    
        If($_.Type -eq "General"){
            $string +=  $_.CompleteName
        } ElseIf($_.Type -eq "Version"){
            $string +=  $_.Channel
        }
    }
    $string -join "`t"
} | Get-Random
```

**Output**

```powershell
folder-2    channel1
```

Comment: Hi Matt,

Yess!

Please can you omit the haeder (not Tb version)

This is transportable for me:

    folder-1     channel2

Merci,
Greats
Arnold